# Page_ClientValidate is undefined in formview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have validators inside a `<asp:formview>`, in order to show custom validation I am using

```
if (!Page_ClientValidate("groupName")) {}
```

I am getting an error Object Expected. How can I validate client side from the form view?

I use `Page_ClientValidate` for `<asp:listview>` and there

Comment: Can you edit your question, it's a bit unclear. Is the code you're trying to run on the client (JavaScript) or the server (codebehind)?

Comment: The validation is client side. The validators are inside a form view. Validation for list view work fine. Why does the Page_ClientValidate throw this error when called from a button click from the form view?

Answer (score 13):

The `Page_ClientValidate` function may sometimes be undefined, e.g. if there are no validators on the page. Check if `typeof Page_ClientValidate === "function"` before calling it.

Answer (score 1):

This would also occur if all validator's EnableClientScript properties are set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Call the following Javascript function whenever you want and pass the validation group name of your form to it..

```
        function ValidateForm(ValidationGroupName)
        {
          var validated=Page_ClientValidate(ValidationGroupName); 
          if(validated)
          {
            //do the logic here
            return true;
          }
          else
          {
            return false;
          }
        }
```

Hope this will help you....